# knex migrate throws error relation already exists

Tags: postgresql, heroku, knex.js, heroku-postgres, node-postgres

I use [Heroku Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql) database and [knexjs](http://knexjs.org/) as SQL query builder in my node.js application. I try to run the latest [knex migration](http://knexjs.org/#Migrations), but I get error `relation already exists`. When I try to create the table by sql command `CREATE TABLE`, it works without any issues.

**knexfile.js**

```
// Update with your config settings.

require('dotenv').config({ path: require('find-config')('.env') });

module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'pg',
    useNullAsDefault: true,
    connection: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    searchPath: ['knex', 'public'],
  },

  staging: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  },

  production: {
    client: 'postgresql',
    connection: {
      database: 'my_db',
      user: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    pool: {
      min: 2,
      max: 10
    },
    migrations: {
      tableName: 'knex_migrations'
    }
  }
};
```

- the latest migration file

**migrations/20180120183247_users_test.js**

```
/* eslint func-names: 0 */

exports.up = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('users', (table) => {
      table.increments('id').primary();
      table.string('user_name', 100);
      table.text('password');
      table.string('email', 254);
    });
};

exports.down = function (knex) {
  return knex.schema
    .dropTableIfExists('users');
};
```

When I run command:

```
knex migrate:latest --env development
```

I get error:

```
Using environment: development
Knex:warning - migration file "20180120184707_initial_schema.js" failed
Knex:warning - migration failed with error: create table "users" ("id" serial primary key, "user_name" varchar(100), "password" text, "email" varchar(254)) - relation "users" already exists
error: relation "users" already exists
    at Connection.parseE (.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:546:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:371:19)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:239:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:197:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:589:20)
```

If I connect to database and run command:

```
select * from users;
```

I get:

```
ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
LINE 1: select * from users;
```

In Heroku Postgres settings I run Reset Database to delete all data. I waited for 2-3 minutes and then tried to run the latest migration again, but I got the same error message.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I didn't know `knex migrate:latest` command runs all migration files so the table `users` was created in previous migration file and that was the issue.

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question hoping for an easy solution so in case anyone else is wondering here's what you can do to fix this:

**If your db truly does match the migration file:**

Go into the `knex_migrations` table (or the table where the migrations are being recorded if you renamed it something else) and add a row with the name of the migration file in question in the `name` column.

To check that this is working correctly try `knex migrate:list`

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure knex is running files with the same names in the migration table. For example check the migration table and make sure it already has:
20180120184707_initial_schema.js

If it doesn't you probably created the table previously using a different file. This can happen if  you ran the app locally previous using ts-node and use ts-node to interpret the typescript directly then run it using node to interpret the js files that were built for example. ts-node would have already saved the ts file in the knex migrations table and node may be trying the js file.